# Multiple Join in one result set

Tags: sql-server

LEFT JOIN Logic in below: Require Left join.. I don't want union join. Below the sample sql query I gave.Thank you in advance.I need below logic

```
LEFT JOIN SQL3 to SQL1 where SQL3.model_id = SQL1.model_id
LEFT JOIN SQL3 to SQL2 where SQL3.model_id = SQL2.model_id
```

SQL #1:

```
SELECT t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, COUNT(t1.Catg_code) AS m_cnt
FROM model t1, car t2
WHERE t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  AND t1.model = 'CD' 
GROUP BY t1.Model_id,t1.Model_num
```

SQL #2:

```
SELECT t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, COUNT(t1.Catg_code) AS e_cnt
FROM model t1, car t2
WHERE t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  AND t1.model = 'EM' 
GROUP BY t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num
```

SQL #3:

```
SELECT t1.Model_id, t1.prod_cd, t3.startdate, t3.enddate 
FROM prod t1, master t3
WHERE t1.model_id = t3.model_id
```

How to make all above SQL result sets into one result?

This is the desired result:

````
Model_id  Model_num   m_cnt   e_cnt   startdate    enddate
-------------------------------------------------------------
011       100001        3       4     04/04/2020   04/04/2020
022       200001        1       2     05/05/2019   05/06/2019```
````

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Time to stop using 1989 syntax; that `LEFT JOIN` logic hasn't been supported since 2005. Time to upgrade to the ANSI-92 syntax; it's been out for 28 years so you're quite late to the party.

Comment: NIce spot @marc_s I'd definately go as far as to say it's an exact dupe. If you don't feel this is true, Div, then please @ me after explaining why in your question and I'll be happy to revoke the lock.